# Can i connect batteries (both 12v and SLA) of different amperage (100amp with 180amp) in parallels?

Tags: battery-charging

I have a 250W solar panel connected to a 12V 100A (SLA) battery through a charge controller (12 and 24V). A 1100W inverter is also connected to the battery.

Now I want to connect a 12V 180A battery in parallel to it. Is it possible? What effect will it have on the batteries?

Comment: First, be clear on the difference between A and Ah and make sure the question is the one you mean to ask. Also, mention the type of both batteries - if they are both SLA, say so. Charging two dissimilar batteries is possible under SOME circumstances, and there are switches to allow connecting either or both (e.g. domestic and starter batteries on a boat) but there's no way to tell from the question if YOUR circumstances are OK. Search "battery isolator/changeover switch"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on what the charger is doing.  The simplest ones don't attempt to fully charge the battery and instead provide a constant voltage of 13.8 (or sometimes 13.6) volts, which will mostly but not fully recharge a lead acid battery of most any type. If your "charge controller" is that type then putting the batteries in parallel should work.  If the charge controller is a fancier one that actually monitors the rate at which the battery is charging and adjusts the charge current as it goes, then putting two dissimilar batteries in parallel could end in tears, because the way that charger works depends on putting the battery to a substantially higher voltage while it's still sucking up the current.  If one battery is fully charged but the other one is sucking ap all the current the charger can offer, then the fully charged battery will overcharge, a situation that can be bad for the battery but also for you if it swells up like a beachball then pops just as you walk in to inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

Lead acid batteries don't have a very predictable voltage to charge-level relationship so paralleling dissimilar units is likely to end badly.