# Can three 7Ah batteries be connected with one 22Ah battery?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, parallel, battery-operated, series

I have three 7Ah 12V SLA batteries and one 22Ah 12V SLA battery. I want to make a 24V system.

Is it safe to connect three 7Ah batteries in parallel to form 7x3= 21≤ Ah and connect that in series with the 22Ah battery to form= 24V 22Ah?

I will require 250W power from the lead acid batteries.

Edit- I need to use them for my ebike. In my case if I only discharge them by maximum 50 percentage and put an auto cutoff module to stop my batteries from discharging beyond a certain voltage( in this case, 25v) , will they be safe enough to use together. Also I initially believed that because their ah will be quite similar i won't face any problems regardless of safety measures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can i connect batteries (both 12v and SLA) of different amperage (100amp with 180amp) in parallels?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/540695/can-i-connect-batteries-both-12v-and-sla-of-different-amperage-100amp-with-18)

Comment: Nope this is different

Comment: Generally it's bad practice to combine mismatched batteries.  Can you do this?  Sure.  Will it blow up in your face?  Maybe, probably not.  Is it totally safe?  Nope.  I wouldn't do it and I'm kinda brave and stupid about this stuff....

Comment: Pls read the question again.... I'm connecting 3 similar batteries in parallel to match with the fourth battery. Recap- 3 7ah battery in parallel to form 21ah and then that 21ah in series with a single 22ah battery.

Comment: You can, but you should not.

Comment: Thanks. Edited the question

Comment: It should work, but you would have to be careful not to over-charge or over-discharge any of the batteries. Not just due to the 1Ah mismatch, but also different wear and tear. The battery doesn't know it's in series or parallel, so it's fine as long as each individual battery is fine.

Comment: I think user253751 is one of the only people who understand this question. Thanks dude....I'm even installing an auto cutoff module just for safety

Answer (score 2):

If you put batteries of unequal rating in series one will discharge before the other and possibly even reverse polarity causing permanent damage.

Do not do what you are suggesting except for short periods while being carefully observed.

After you have consumed 21Ah from the combination the 3x7Ah will be fully discharged while there is remaining charge in the other. If you carry on discharging the 12V 22Ah will cause the polarity of the smaller battery to reverse and possibly be permanently damaged.

Also the actual capacity will not be identical to  that on the label and will change as the battery ages.

Comment: Hi sir! Thanks for understanding the question and taking the time to answer. I need to use them for my ebike. In my case if I only discharge them by maximum 50 percentage and put an auto cutoff module to stop my batteries from discharging beyond a certain voltage( in this case, 25v) , will they be safe enough to use together. Also I initially believed that because their ah will be quite similar i won't face any problems regardless of safety measures.

Answer (score 0):

**In short, YES I see as a viable solution, considering the following conditions**:

(**1**) If the Four batteries have same chemistry and manufacturer, they may follow the same discharge profile.

(**2**) If all batteries are of similar age and user history, they may have aged similarly.
In fact, using [this YUASA guidebook for SLA Batteries](https://gsyuasa-es.com/Downloads/NP_Application_manual.pdf), the discharge curves are plotted as a percentage of nominal capacity C, and shall have similar discharge profile.

(**3**) As 250W under 24~25V corresponds to
**i_disch = 10A**, which corresponds to **0.5C** of a 20Ah battery.
(**4**) If the battery bank is composed of same chemistry, manufacturer and type as:
**3x 7Ah + 1x 22Ah**, it would be approximately AP **equivalent to 1x 24V ~20Ah** discharging **at 0.5C**.  See highlighted yellow curves in the following graph.
Then, the expected unbalance between the two 12V banks is ~= 5%. If you control the undervoltage **V_cutoff ~= 20V**, as the Yuasa’s graph shows from the above mentioned link, I would proceed as you intended.
[image].

**Extending e-bike’s Running time**:
(Reverting from 24V to 12V)
In case you e-bike runs out of juice at 24V & 10A (~ 0.5C @ 20Ah), you might need just 6A @ 12V. If you reroute all batteries in parallel, it would make a battery bank as 12V x 40Ah, where 6A would be then 0.17C or C/6.
For this, the discharge curve wold revert to the plotted green curve, where **V_cutoff= 10.4V @ 12V** bank (again, assuming Yuasa’s data as valid for you).
You can do this with a DPDT manual switch or relay, just like the rewiring of transformer windings for 110/220VAC. Obviously the Cutoff voltages will be different, as said above.
[image]
Doing this, you can have some **extra running time** (at lower speeds) to reach your home or recharging point.